# Microsoft Graph API, password grant option

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In [this](https://medium.com/nearsoft-solutions/azure-active-directory-authentication-oauth-2-0-type-password-e119f9a5ad4c) topic, the author explains how to get an access token based on users login and password, skipping the authorization dialog.

I could hit the endpoint and get an access token, and refresh token:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/348a...6e4/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&\
client_id=6d5f...64f&client_secret=g...f2&username=user@Domain.com&\
password=P@ssW0RD&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/&\
scope=user.read%20calendars.read%20MailboxSettings.Read%20Mail.read%20Mail.Send

//RESPONSE
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "User.Read",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "ext_expires_in": "3600",
    "expires_on": "1559602338",
    "not_before": "1559598438",
    "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV...KJmNhyz5bvhzCWiFA",
    "refresh_token": "AQABAAA...VkgAA",
    "id_token": "eyJ0...xLjAifQ."
}
```

But when I tried to get the user´s email, I get an error:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?\
$select=sender,subject,ReceivedDateTime&\
$filter=ReceivedDateTime%20ge%202019-05-01&$top=20

RESPONSE

{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "e35f...94",
            "date": "2019-06-03T21:39:40"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this authentication method still valid to Microsoft Graph API? If not, Is there any another way to get the user authorization using only login and password, without any user interaction, just getting his login and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically specify `scope` with the v1 Endpoint. That model is on only supported with the newer v2 Endpoint (see [Scopes, not Resources](http://Scopes,%20not%20resources) in the documentation).

In order access the user's mailbox, you'll need to add `Mail.Read` to your application's registration in the Azure Portal.

Keep in mind that you'll either need an Admin to consent to your application for all users in the tenant or have each user sign-in interactively at least once so they can consent themselves.

I'd also be remiss if I didn't point out that using the Password grant is almost *always* a bad idea. It is fundamentally less secure than every other OAuth Grant.

Comment: We solved the access denied access with an admin consent, and it´s working now. We aware that its the best and safer way, but it fits what we need in this project. Thanks for the help!